# What files can be removed before deploying a VueJS project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, web-hosting

I was recently working on a `Vue.js` project and I am done with the "Beta-Version". I want to deploy my website to an online server and share it with the world. I used `npm run build` to generate the scripts in the `dist` folder, and now I want to upload the files to the server, but I doubt that all the files are necessary to be uploaded. I guess I should remove some files that don't effect the user experience.

**The Question: What are the files that can be removed before deploying a Vue.js project?**

Note: I'm not talking only about the `dist` folder, I'm taking about removable files and folders in the root project directory, that contains `dist` and `package.json` and `node_modules`.

Comment: You can safely remove all the .map files, nothing more.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky There are no files with this extension in the whole project directory..

Comment: Then there is probably nothing to remove, all files in your dist folder are needed.

Comment: I don't mean the dist folder, I mean the whole project folder including `package.json` and `node_modules` and others..

Comment: Did you uploaded all the files on your hosting server? Not only files located in dist subfolder?

Comment: Yeah because I don't know what files are useful and what are disposable.

Comment: Ahh... So, delete from hosting all the files you uploaded. And then upload only the files located in dist folder. They are "dist-ribution" files, only files you need to upload on your hosting.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of build process is to put any and all files and nothing else necessary for deployment into a folder, in this case, dist folder.
Oops. This was meant to be a comment.

Comment: I did deploy only the contents of `dist` folder and it just worked fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn’t delete any file in dist folder unless you know for sure you don’t need it.
If you do know that certain file doesn’t belong, it shouldn’t be there to begin with.
But unless you modified build portion to add something you don’t need, it most likely doesn’t contain any that shouldn’t be there.

Comment: I'm not talking about the dist folder only, I mean the whole project directory, including `package.json` and `node_modules`, I don't think I need all of these..

Comment: You only need to upload dist folder. So yes, you can skip uploading anything outside of dist folder.

Comment: Only the `dist` and the `index.html`?

Comment: index.html should really be inside dist folder with build process.